# Access to filter var attribute?

Tags: magento

In Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer_View there is a variable called $_filters, that loops through and displays properties in the $_filter var.  Whenever I try to var dump this variable, my server throws an error. This behavior is completely mysterious.  Does anyone know if I can get back to the attribute code?  I'd like to do something like this:

```
$_filter->getAttribute()->getAttributeCode();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `$_filter->getAttributeModel()->getAttributeCode()`?

Answer (score 0):

```
public function getFilters()
{
    $filters = array();
    if ($categoryFilter = $this->_getCategoryFilter()) {
        $filters[] = $categoryFilter;
    }

    $filterableAttributes = $this->_getFilterableAttributes();
    foreach ($filterableAttributes as $attribute) {
        $filters[] = $this->getChild($attribute->getAttributeCode().'_filter');
    }

    return $filters;
}
```

you can see where the variable setting to this array takes place and how the attribute code is used in this class. Note that this is an array containing view objects not a object itself and dumping out all this just eats up your server memory. And of course you can't call methods on this array.

So there is no actual way to get this code out of this array and you probably have more success in template or subobject level or if you need this in the same class you can get the filters out of $this->_getFilterableAttributes() method or you can try and iterate over each filters array member and their sub-members

```
$filters['0']->getItems()
```